# Why does the priority of a process change after receiving a message in QNX?

Tags: unix, operating-system, scheduling, qnx, thread-priority

I wrote a simple `C` program and compiled it with `gcc` as usual. When it starts, the default priority is `10`. Using the `sched_setparam()` API, I boost the priority of process to `100`. I noticed that when another process with priority of `10` sends a message to the first process via `MsgSend()` API, the priority of the first process goes back to `10`!

I'm wondering why does this happen? Is there such a similar behavior in other POSIX-compliant operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

Please , see this.  http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.0/neutrino/sys_arch/ipc.html#Priority_inheritance_messages

This behaviour is called "priority inheritance". This message-driven priority inheritance avoids priority-inversion problems.